# Upload on Google Drive from our website

Tags: javascript, php, upload, google-drive-api

I was wondering if it was possible ? I want to allow a user to upload a file from my website with his Google Account and after, show the file on the website.
Is it possible ?
Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a facility for this:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Otherwise you'll need to use something like CURL to login to the web interface.

Comment: Yeah, already seen but i can't find how to make it via PHP or other classic web languages..

Comment: It's not web language specific. It's an API by the looks of things. You'll need to get to grips with something like CURL. There is a good wrapper here:

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

See the CURL documentation in the PHP manual.